# PHP array_search not working with certain needles

Tags: php

I've got a function that is used in a loop, however it is not working at all, here's example of my code

```
    function is_banned_category($a) {
    if(!is_array($a)) {
        echo "returning false <Br/>";
        return false;
    }
    $banned_list = array(
        'Shopping',
        'Product Info'
    );
    foreach($a as $cat) {
        if(array_search($cat,$banned_list)) {
            $return = true;
        } else {
            echo "Not found in:'{$cat}' <br/>";
        }
    }
        return $return;
    }
    $a = array('Shopping');
    if(is_banned_category($a)) {
echo "Item will not be added as it's in banned category";
}
```

Which would produce:

> Item will not be added as it's in banned category

Am I missing something obvious here? It works with "Product Info" but not "Shopping"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_search($cat,$banned_list)` returns `0`, witch causes expression to evaluate to false. use `in_array()` or evaluate using Identical Operator `===`

Comment: Oh cr*p, yes it returns the key, that makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Comment: @InsaneCoder , you do realize that I can only accept best answer after some time? I'd suggest not getting on people's back before you even know how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

The function [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) will return the index of the occurrence if found (which could be 0, which evaluates to `false`), or else `false` if not found, so you must use

```
if(array_search($cat, $banned_list) !== false) {
  [.. do your stuff .. ]
}
```

to perform the check, or else you could do

```
if(in_array($cat, $banned_list)) {
  [.. do your stuff .. ]
}
```

which, IMHO, is a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

array_search returns the key of array value if exist, so in your case 
array key of Shopping is "0"

```
 if(array_search($cat,$banned_list)) // return 0
```

So else part will be worked